# Wifi Direct P2P not working on Android 10+ devices, Unable to discover devices

Tags: android, android-10.0, wifi-direct, wifip2p, android-11

Hi I am working on devices in which I need to connect devices using Wi-fi Direct. My code is working on all devices but discovery is failing all the time for Android 10+ devices.

I am asking for required permissions implicitly as well as explicitly.

in manifest I am asking these permissions.

```
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"
        android:required="true" />
```

I am asking these permissions explicitly as well.

Here is my code which I am trying [Working for all devices below Android 10+]

```
private void discoverWifi() {

      if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !=  
           PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        wifiP2pManager.discoverPeers(wifiChannel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                connectionStatus.setText("Discover Start");
            }
    
            @Override
            public void onFailure(int i) {
                connectionStatus.setText("Discover not Start");
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can anyone please help?

Comment: What error code do you get inside `onFailure`?

Comment: I am getting error code 2 in onFailure on Emulator.

Comment: anyone please??

Comment: Error code 2 corresponds to `WifiP2pManager .BUSY`. I'm pretty sure, emulator doesn't support P2P. Do you have real device to test?

Comment: Thanks man !!! .. I managed to test on real device and I am getting error code 0 in onFailure.

Comment: Zero is just `ERROR` constant. Check your logcat for any related system errors. Btw, are you executing this code in foreground?

Comment: Also try setting `targetSdkVersion 28` (not an actual solution, but may bring some light on the issue)

Comment: I executing this on main thread only and after changing this targetSdkVersion 28 I am still getting 0 error code.

Comment: I were asking not about thread, I meant if your app is open when code is executed. Have you found anything in useful in system logs?

Answer (score 1):

on Android 10+ devices,you should open the location or the discovery will fail